# UTF-8 minus sign rejected in python command-line arguments

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, command-line, argparse

I am running python 2.6 on Ubuntu Lucent and having trouble getting the minus sign in negative command-line arguments to be interpreted properly, especially when the call to the script is initiated through the OS via Rails (using backquotes).  In particular, the minus sign seems to be coming in as UTF-8.

When command-line arguments are interpreted manually, as in:

```
lng = float(sys.argv[4])
```

it triggers the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): ‐122.768
```

As a hack, I can get around this by matching on the first three bytes as '\xe2', '\x80', and '\x90', and replacing them with my own negative sign.

When command-line arguments are interpreted through argparse (ver. 1.2.1), as in:

```
parser.add_argument('--coords', metavar='Coord', dest='coordinates', type=float, nargs=3, help='Latitude, Longitude, and Altitude')
```

it triggers the error:

```
sC.py: error: argument --coords: invalid float value: '\xe2\x80\x90122.76838'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you actually getting that minus sign into your Ruby code? Use an editor that works right, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to use your hack and tell argparse to expect a string.

As far as Python, your system, and RoR are concerned `-` and `―` aren't related in any way.  If you want to solve this problem (instead of hack it) you have go up to the rails code, and see where it gets its data from.  Somewhere along the line *fancy output* was important.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'fancy output' and not sure whether we're using that, but will look into it.  For the moment, I'm telling argparse to expect a string.

Comment: Certain software -- usually [word processing](http://bit.ly/uauIBD) or blogging -- will turn two dashes into one long dash.  It looks nice for the end user, but programs don't know how to handle it usually.

Answer (score 3):

Your input data contains a Unicode character that isn't the standard ascii hyphen.

```
import unicodedata as ud
data = '\xe2\x80\x90122.76838'
unicode_data = data.decode('utf8')
print repr(ud.name(unicode_data[0]))
print repr(ud.name(u'-')) # An ascii hyphen
```

Output:

```
'HYPHEN'
'HYPHEN-MINUS'
```

While they may look the same when printed, they are not.  Restrict or sanitize the input.

```
print float(unicode_data.replace(u'\N{HYPHEN}',u'-'))
```

Output:

```
-122.76838
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a cleaner way of doing the substitution than I had. Still, I'd prefer if it were not necessary.